# Use of IIS Express from same user

Tags: c#, iis, iis-express

I'm have multiple windows users, one is administrator and another one is standard user. When I start IIS Express with admin user in C# working fine when I switch to standard user and running the same application. Whereas if I start IIS Express in c# with standard user, facing issue when I switch to admin user to use same application. That IIS Express is not starting for the standard user when it is running with admin user.

Also if both the user accounts are admin, when i switch between the users and work on the application which is starting IIS then IIS is running for separately for both users.

Here is my code,

```
new ProcessStartInfo { FileName = iisInstalledPath + "iisexpress.exe", WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden, Arguments = @"/path:""" + location + "\" /port:" + availablePort, UseShellExecute = true, CreateNoWindow = true, LoadUserProfile = true };
```

I need to start IIS separately for standard and admin user via code.

Comment: iisexpress is useful for development purpose only. Any Production grade system should be using IIS which is controlled as a service at the system level and not at user level.

Comment: Please go read up on how to use a web server, specifically roles, authentication and authorization. What you are attempting to do is not how you should use the technology.

Comment: If you are determind then pick a new account thats neither the original user or administrator, determine what actual permissions are needed and you can use runas from either.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line You probably forgot to add `/systray:false`.